# How to insert a search result into a table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code that I've got to search and it just appears next to each other. Can I put html within php and how would this be done? Or should I make a table below the form?

```
   <?php

  include ('database_conn.php');

    $output = '';

    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
      $search = $_POST['search'];
      $search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search);

      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE stud_id LIKE '%$search%'") or die ("Could not search");
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

      if($count == 0){
        $output = "There was no search results!";

      }else{

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


          $stud_id = $row ['stud_id'];
          $module = $row ['module'];
          $attendance_status = $row ['attendance_status'];

          $output .='<div> '.$stud_id.''.$module.''.$attendance_status.'</div>';




        }

      }
    }

    ?>
```

This is the form that I've got in the HTML to search

```
<form action ="CM0671_attendance.php" method = "post">

      <input name="search" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Student ID"/>

      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search"/>

      </form>
```

Comment: Consider putting it in an isolated html file.

Comment: Please provide the file name in which each code part reside.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace your while with this:


echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Module</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
          $stud_id = $row ['stud_id'];
          $module = $row ['module'];
          $attendance_status = $row ['attendance_status'];
              echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$stud_id}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$module}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$attendance_status}</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table><br>";
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest having such a large block of php inline with html. Link out of php where needed and echo the data that way.